# Node JS - json to jsongraph converter

Tags: json, node.js, falcor

I need to convert normal JSON to JSON Graph. I tried [json-graphify](https://github.com/greim/json-graphify) but the "import" statement in it throws an error saying it is not supported now.

Comment: I assume you are not using es6 compatible node. Try using babel transpiler https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/cli/ . Then import should work and json-graphify would work as intended

Comment: What's the use case here? Why do you want to do this? I work in the Falcor team, and understanding the use case will help me answer better.

Answer (score 1):

The code contained in json-graphify's `src/` directory is the prebuilt/precompiled code, which uses syntax not yet available to node or browsers.  The module's author didn't check in the compiled code to github, though it is available on npm (notice the project's [main entry file](https://github.com/greim/json-graphify/blob/master/package.json#L5) points to `lib/index.js`, not `src/index.js`).

You either need to: compile it yourself via `babel src --out-dir lib --optional runtime` (see the project's [compile script](https://github.com/greim/json-graphify/blob/master/package.json#L9)), or install the module via npm.  The former approach will build the compiled code into the `lib/` directory.  The latter (probably the recommended approach) will download a precompiled version that can be used via `const graphify = require('json-graphify')`.

Comment: Compiling with Babel didn't work either..... Seems like there is some code issue in json-graphify package. Is there any other way to generate json-graph from json?